# unsorted matrix search algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix

is there a suitable algorithm that allows a program to search through an unsorted matrix in search of the biggest prime number within. The matrix is of size m*n and may be populated with other prime numbers and non-primes. The search must find the biggest prime.

I have studied the divide and conquer algorithms, and binary trees, and step-wise searches, but all of these deal with sorted matrices.

Comment: If the matrix is unsorted and the program has no other information about it, your only option is to brute-force search every element.

Comment: In the absence of additional information you may want to use a parallel scan of the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it doesn't matter if you are using m * n matrix or vector with m * n elements. Generally speaking, you will have to visit each matrix element at least once, as it is not sorted. There are few hints to make process faster.

1. If it is big matrix, you should visit elements row by row (and not column by column) as matrix is stored that way in memory so that elements from the same row will likely be in the cache once you access one of them.
2. Testing number's primeness is the most costly part of your task so if numbers in matrix are not too big, you can use Eratosthenes' sieve algorithm to make lookup of prime numbers in advance. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes
3. If you don't use Eratosthenes' sieve, maybe it will be beneficial if you sort your numbers before algorithm so that you can test numbers from the greatest to the smallest. In that case, your algorithm can stop once the first prime number is found. If you don't sort it, you will have to test all numbers, which is probably slowest method.

Comment: If you do use the Sieve of Eratosthenes, sorting will actually make things worse (in theory and probably in practice), since the SoE needs to generate and save all smaller primes than the number you're currently testing against anyway.

Comment: @j_random_hacker That's probably true. Lookup is very fast and sorting wouldn't give you anything valuable. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; m++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
       if ((array[i][j] == *a prime number*) 
           && (array[i][j] > biggestPrime))
       {
           biggestPrime = array[i][j];
       }
    }
}
```